# how to plot graph of Precision and Recall in Matlab?

Tags: matlab, graph, plot, precision-recall

i have three values for precision and recall as follows:

```
precision = 0.4     recall= 0.45
precision= 0.58     recall= 0.52
precision= 0.6      recall= 0.53
```

above values show when precision is 0.4 recall is 0.45 and vice versa, i want to plot these results in a graph which should show increase and decrease in precision and recall values with respect to each other.

i want to show the result of these values in a single graph which should show 3 curves(lines) with different colors for different representation.

Comment: you should provide an example plot to illustrate the result you are aiming at; I have no idea how you would plot 3 lines based on 3 discrete points.

Comment: Are you sure you don't just want 1 line connecting those points? You do not have enough info for 3 lines...

Comment: @m.s. actually these are three values are obtained from three different experiments each experiment results in 1 precision and recall value,i want to draw there curves in a single graph so that i can compare them.

Answer (score 1):

I am mostly guessing at what you are trying to achieve to be honest, but possibly all you are looking for is the "hold all" command. If this is not what you want to achieve, please provide an example of you are plotting a single curve, so we can push you in the right direction of how to expand on that.

```
figure
hold all
plot(calculate_my_results(0.4,0.45))
plot(calculate_my_results(0.58,0.52))
plot(calculate_my_results(0.6,0.53))
```

Comment: actually i am trying to compare the curves for these 3 pair of values that's why i want to plot them separately with separate colors, thanks for your answer but i am getting error `Undefined function 'calculate_my_results' for input arguments of type 'double'` and no output is displayed, thanks once again

Answer (score 0):

To see how the recall varies as a function of precision you can plot the one variable against the other. It will only produce one line, as noted by the other commenters, but it will show you the relationship between the two.

```
recall = [0.45 0.52 0.53];
precision = [0.4 0.58 0.6];
plot(recall, precision)
xlabel('Recall'); ylabel('Precision');
```

If indeed you want three lines then michael_0815's answer is the one you want.

Comment: thanks for your answer but i am not getting any display of result